# c# dictionary assign variable's value

Tags: c#, variables, dictionary

I having some troubles with assigning the value of variables to dictionary in c#.

Here is the example. I have the following class:

```
public class test_class
{
    public int val1;
    public int val2;
}
```

And I'm running the following code:

```
Dictionary<int, test_class> tmp_dict = new Dictionary<int, test_class>();

tmp_test.val1 = 1;
tmp_test.val2 = 1;
tmp_dict.Add(1, tmp_test);

tmp_test.val1 = 2;
tmp_test.val2 = 2;
tmp_dict.Add(2, tmp_test);

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, test_class> dict_item in tmp_dict)
{        
    Console.WriteLine("key: {0}, val1: {1}, val2: {2}", dict_item.Key, dict_item.Value.val1, dict_item.Value.val2);
}
```

Now, I would expected to get the following output (key1 with values of 1)

```
key: 1, val1: 1, val2: 1
key: 2, val1: 2, val2: 2
```

But I get the following one (key1 also got value of 2):

```
key: 1, val1: 2, val2: 2
key: 2, val1: 2, val2: 2
```

It seems like the assignment was by reference and not by value...
Maybe you can help me assign the real value of the class variable and not it's reference?

Comment: It is because test_class is a reference type. Use different variables.

Answer (score 4):

You are only creating a single instance of the `test_class`, and add that instance twice to the dictionary. By modifying it before adding it to the dictionary again, you are also affecting the instance that was already added—because it’s the *same* instance, there are just multiple references to it in the dictionary.

So instead of modifying one object, create new ones:

```
test_class tmp_test;

// create a new object
tmp_test = new test_class();
tmp_test.val1 = 1;
tmp_test.val2 = 1;
tmp_dict.Add(1, tmp_test);

// create another new object
tmp_test = new test_class();
tmp_test.val1 = 2;
tmp_test.val2 = 2;
tmp_dict.Add(2, tmp_test);
```

Since a new object was assigned to `tmp_test`, the reference that is added to the dictionary is now the reference to the *new* object, so it is independent of the first object that we added to the dictionary.

But keep in mind that the objects are still mutable, so you can do things like this just fine and it will modify the objects in the dictionary (and wherever else a reference to them exists):

```
tmp_dict[1].val1 = 123;
tmp_dict[2].val2 = 42;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is absolutetly correct, it has something to do with the references. As you simply change the properties of your instance of `test_class` those changes are reflected by all references to that instance. You may consider create a new instance:

```
tmp_test = new test_class();
tmp_test.val1 = 1;
tmp_test.val2 = 1;
tmp_dict.Add(1, tmp_test);

tmp_test1 = new test_class();
tmp_test1.val1 = 2;
tmp_test1.val2 = 2;
tmp_dict1.Add(2, tmp_test1);
```

Alternativly re-assign your reference `tmp_test` to a new instance: `tmp_test = new test_class()`.

NB: Class-names should be **PascalCase** (in your case `TestClass`)

Comment: I think "by reference" is an unfortunate choice of words here. The value of `tmp_test` is copied into the dictionary - but that value *is* a reference. This isn't the same as the "by reference" of a `ref` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it a bit easier:

```
tmp_dict.Add(1, new test_class{val1 = 1, val2 = 1;});
tmp_dict.Add(2, new test_class{val1 = 2, val2 = 2;});
```

Comment: even nicer with collection initializer: `var tmp_dict = new Dictionary<int, test_class>
   {
    { 1, new test_class{val1 = 1, val2 = 1} },
    { 2, new test_class{val1 = 2, val2 = 2} }
   };`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int, test_class> tmp_dict = new Dictionary<int, test_class>();

test_class tmp_test = new test_class();
tmp_test.val1 = 1;
tmp_test.val2 = 1;
tmp_dict.Add(1, tmp_test);

tmp_test = new test_class(); //You Need to initialize the variable again.
tmp_test.val1 = 2;
tmp_test.val2 = 2;
tmp_dict.Add(2, tmp_test);

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, test_class> dict_item in tmp_dict)
                        {
Console.WriteLine("key: {0}, val1: {1}, val2: {2}", dict_item.Key, dict_item.Value.val1, dict_item.Value.val2);
                        }
```

Good Luck